# jQuery async:false and Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

When a user clicks on a link, I want to make an ajax call and wait for the call to complete before redirecting the user. Initially I used `preventDefault()` and `window.location` to achieve the result, but that prevented a user from doing **Ctrl + Click (new tab)**.

So I ended up doing this, but for some reason the ajax call is never made in Firefox:

```
$('a.item-link').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://123.456.789.012/c",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'userId'   : '1234'
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 1500
    });

    return true;
});
```

Any idea how could I do this synchronous call in Firefox?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why would you ever want AJAX to be `async: false`?? That is the entire purpose of AJAX

Comment: Why don't you just `preventDefault()` unless the `Ctrl` key is down?

Comment: Do I have any other way that would do the call, redirects the user, and that still works for Ctrl+Click? As I said, preventDefault and window.location spoils the user experience.

Comment: In what way is FireFox upset?

Comment: "*Cross-domain requests and `dataType: "jsonp"` requests do not support synchronous operation.*" (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) JSONP is, by definition, asynchronous, because it requires loading a new `<script>` element.

Comment: @JeffB: That seems to be a solution. Tomalak: Sorry, edited the question.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS If you want to stop the rest of your script while the Ajax request runs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JeffB and @bobber205, I ended up doing this:

```
$('a.item-link').on('click', function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        var newTab = true;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _this = this;
        var newTab = false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://123.456.789.012/c",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'userId'   : '1234'
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 1500,
        success: function(){
            if(!newTab){
                window.location = $(_this).prop('href');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            if(!newTab){
                window.location = $(_this).prop('href');
            }
        }
    });

    if(newTab){
        return true;
    }
});
```

I am just checking if `ctrl` key was pressed during the click and taking appropriate actions.

Thanks for the hint, experts. Sometimes, the simplest thoughts require reminder from others. Great community this is!

Answer (score 2):

Make your element a button and don't do the redirection until the ajax call is done. Open in new window if ctrl button was down before the call was made.